# Change Password Not working with Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

We have created a Azure AD User using a Graph API and using custom policies for signIn. The user is able to sign In with the user principal name address(xyz@domain.onmicrosoft.com)

Now, Recently we have changed the way user is getting created. Instead of adding the userPrincipal Name we are updating the SignInNames Property of user. So user is able to login with just the userName without appending domain to it.
But, after making this change the Change Password is not working. It says the "username or password is Invalid".

Could you please help us on this.
Thanks!

Comment: How are you attempting to change password? With Graph, or with a policy?

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret we are attempting to do it via policy.
On first page- it recognizes the user and takes us to the second page asking the old password and new password. one trying to update the password on second page. It errors saying "invalid username or password"

Comment: Hi @prateek Is this a sign-in-only policy?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett Change Password custom policy created!

Comment: @prateek Do you mean [this custom policy](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/scenarios/password-change)? Have you changed the `client_id`, `IdTokenAudience` and `resource_id` properties in the "login-NonInteractive" technical profile to those for your Azure AD B2C tenant?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett yes I am using the same :)

Comment: Thank you @prateek did you change the aforementioned properties to those for your Azure AD B2C tenant?

Answer (score 0):

When you created the user with only the username, how did you set the value of  `forceChangePasswordNextLogin`?

If you set it `true`, when you logging in, you will get the error "username or password is Invalid". But if the value is `false`, you could use the username to succeed login.

Comment: If there is anything update, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: I have not set the property as true but it is set as false. 
The fist page of chnage password work fine, it recognizes the user and take me to second page where it ask for  old password, new password, and reenter new password.

Here on the second page, when i enter the details, it says, invalid username /password.